# Removing specific rows in common using dplyr

Tags: r, join, dplyr

So let's say I have a df like this:

**DF1**

```
ID    Name       Age    Color
001   Stephanie  23     Red
002   DJ         
003   Michelle   20     Blue
004   Danny      40     Green
005   Joey       
006   Jesse 
005   Jesse
```

*Let's imagine the data is 1000+ obs and 30+ vars*

So let's say I subset all my vars that had missing info

**DF2 (subset of DF1)**

```
ID    Name       Age    Color
002   DJ         
005   Joey       
006   Jesse  
005   Jesse
```

and in this form, I was able to find some of the info.

**Still DF2**

```
ID    Name       Age    Color
002   DJ         
005   Joey       42     Yellow
006   Jesse      39     Black
005   Jesse
```

How can I update the rows in the original data to have all the info I was only able to update as a subset. Final df should be:

```
ID    Name       Age    Color
001   Stephanie  23     Red
002   DJ         
003   Michelle   20     Blue
004   Danny      40     Green
005   Joey       42     Yellow
006   Jesse      39     Black
005   Jesse
```

Comment: Would ```merge(df1,df2,by="Name")``` provide you with an updated dataframe?

Comment: try using `dplyr::rows_update()`. if I get you right

Comment: there isn't one disticnt coloumn i could match on. i was thinking more of a rbind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a `new_id` column to match distinctly on:

```
#recreating dfs
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006, 005),
                  Name = c("Stephanie", "DJ", "Michelle", "Danny", "Joey", "Jesse", "Jesse"),
                  Age = c(23,"", 20, 40, "", "", ""),
                  Color = c("Red", "", "Blue", "Green", "","",""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
new_id <- 1:nrow(df1)
df1 <- cbind(new_id, df1)

df2 <- data.frame(new_id = c(2,5,6,7),
                  ID = c(002, 005, 006, 005),
                  Name = c("DJ","Joey", "Jesse", "Jesse"),
                  Age = c("",42, 39, ""),
                  Color = c("", "Yellow","Black",""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And then using that as an index to specify which rows you want replaced:

```
#add rows back in
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  if (df1$new_id[i] %in% df2$new_id){
    df1[i,] <- df2[which(df2$new_id == df1$new_id[i]),]
  }
}

> df1
  new_id ID      Name Age  Color
1      1  1 Stephanie  23    Red
2      2  2        DJ           
3      3  3  Michelle  20   Blue
4      4  4     Danny  40  Green
5      5  5      Joey  42 Yellow
6      6  6     Jesse  39  Black
7      7  5     Jesse
```

Or, a `dplyr` solution (using the same df's):

```
> df2 %>% union(df1) %>% distinct(ID, Name, .keep_all = T) %>% arrange(new_id)
  new_id ID      Name Age  Color
1      1  1 Stephanie  23    Red
2      2  2        DJ           
3      3  3  Michelle  20   Blue
4      4  4     Danny  40  Green
5      5  5      Joey  42 Yellow
6      6  6     Jesse  39  Black
7      7  5     Jesse
```

Comment: Yep, just added it!